# Obtener protocolo y dominio PHP

Tags: php, dominio

¿Cómo puedo obtener protocolo y dominio en `php`?

```
$protocol = stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],'https') === true ? 'https://' : 'http://';

$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

Comment: Hola Alberto, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. No entiendo bien tu pregunta... ni tu respuesta... Mira [ask]  para saber como hacer preguntas validas y de calidad. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Esto funciona correctamente

$protocol = stripos($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],'https') === true ? 'https://' : 'http://';

$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];